# HAML/SCSS on web.py

Tags: python, haml, sass, web.py

I've been researching this to no avail. Does anyone know if there is HAML/SCSS support on web.py.

It does not need to be native support, it could be a module that is imported to enable it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want real Ruby HAML, or something very HAML-like? My project (https://github.com/mikeboers/PyHAML) gets pretty close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Sass goes, you can use Ruby's Sass library to process the SCSS and then serve up the CSS output. There's now also an [implementation in C++](https://github.com/hcatlin/sassc) if for some reason you don't want to use Ruby.

Another alternative is to use [LessCSS](http://lesscss.org/), which is implemented in Javascript. During development you can offload all of the processing to the browser, and serve precompiled CSS only in production. I find it to be a pretty comfortable workflow, even though in some ways the implementation is not as polished as Sass's.

Answer (score 0):

There is [ruby gem for scss](http://sass-lang.com/), you just need to run it command-line to compile scss to css.

I use many different things with my webpy app, including additional compass ruby gem for scss and nodejs based coffeescript compiler. I have coffeescript Cake file that runs all command line utilities (to compile scss to css, coffee to js, to minify css and js files, to extract i18n strings for translations).